# Detect unacceptable drag drop in jQuery-ui droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm using `jQuery-ui` `draggable`, `droppable`. My main `container` should only accept `plugin-containers` which also are droppables which accept plugins. Below is the code my code snippet:

```
$("#main").droppable({
                activeClass: "ui-state-default",
                hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
                accept: ".plugin-container",
                drop: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
                    $("<div></div>").html(ui.draggable.html()).appendTo(this).droppable({ accept: '.plugin', drop: function (event, ui) { $('<div></div>').html(ui.draggable.html()).appendTo(this); } }).sortable();
                }

});
```

The problem is that when a plugin is dragged into the main container, I want to:

1. Hightlight Plugin containers that plugin can be dropped
2. If plugin is dropped in the main container show an error message

but the droppable **over** and **drop** methods only fire if the dragged item is acceptable and won't fire for unacceptable drags (in this case .plugin). what can I do here?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLAg6/)

Comment: please create a fiddle !

Comment: @RahulGupta I added the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found **THE EXACT SOLUTION TO YOUR PROBLEM** !!

Check out this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/KgnLq/)

CODE:

```
$("#main").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",

    //accept: ".plugin-container",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {

        if(ui.draggable.hasClass('plugin'))
        {
            alert('This element cannot be dropped here !');
            $(ui.draggable).draggable({ revert: true });
        }   
        else if(ui.draggable.hasClass('plugin-container'))
        {
            //console.log('context = ');
            //console.log(ui.draggable.context);

            $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
            $("<div></div>").addClass('plugin-container')
            .html(ui.draggable.html())
            .appendTo(this)
            .droppable({ 
                accept: '.plugin',
                greedy:true,//this will prevent the parent droppables from receiving the droppable object
                drop: function (event, ui) { 
                    $(ui.draggable).draggable({ revert: false });
                    $('<div></div>')
                    .addClass('plugin')
                    .html(ui.draggable.html())
                    .appendTo(this); 
                } 
            }).sortable();
        }
    }

});

$(".menu div").draggable({
     appendTo: "body",
     helper: "clone"
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot. actually this was a sample and there are lots of plugin types and each container may accept different kinds of plugins. I managed it just like this but the real project is slightly different. thanks again.

Comment: Pleasure to help you ! But really it took a lot of research effort ! But after all somehow I managed to find the precise solution to the problem !

Answer (score 1):

You can make all draggabbles acceptable and then in your over and drop methods filter the wanted/unwanted divs and show error message.

```
drop: function( event, ui ) {
var dropped = ui.draggable.attr('class');
if (dropped == ".plugin") {
  // show alert
} else {

}
```

There is also the '[revert](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#revert)' option that you can use to revert a dragged  element back to its original position.

Comment: I thought of this but it didn't quiet feel right. I thought there might be a better option that I'm missing. ;)